# i don't understand the output in this php code?

Tags: php

I have trouble understanding this code, can please someone explain it to me?

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $func1 = function() use ($i) { echo "$i"; };
    $func2 = function() use (&$i) { echo "$i"; };
    for ( $i=1; $i<=5; $i++ ) {
        $func1();
        $func2();
    }
?>
```

output: 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5

Comment: What is the output you were expecting to see?

Comment: @summea I don't understand how & works in this case.Why is it referencing variable defined in for loop?

Comment: Formatting is really nice :P

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is a perfectly valid question, but probably not the best way to write it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    $func1 = function() use ($i) { echo "$i"; };
    $func2 = function() use (&$i) { echo "$i"; };
    for ( $i=1; $i<=5; $i++ ) {
        $func1();
        $func2();
    }
?>
```

The first definition with `use ($i)` takes the value from the parent scope **when the function is defined** (so, in `$func1`, `$i` will always be `0`). The second function, however, when using `use(&$i)`, is grabbing `$i` value **by reference**, so it will print the actual value of `$i`, not only when defined.

These function definitions are called **anonymous functions**.

More on anonymous functions in the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

=========

So, for `$func1`, `$i` is always `0`.
For `$func2` it will be from `1` to `5` (due to your `for` loop).

**Iteration 1:** func1: $i = 0; func2: $i = 1

**Iteration 2:** func1: $i = 0; func2: $i = 2

...

**Iteration N:** func1: $i = 0; func2: $i = N